# How do I tell if a product is prime eligible in the Amazon Product Advertising API?

Tags: amazon-product-api

Been using the API for about a week now and I can't seem to figure out how to access this data in ItemSearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform an `ItemSearch` the `ResponseGroup` will contain `IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping` which will tell you if it is Prime eligible.

Comment: Thanks for that bit of info. Let me dive into the data and see if you're right. That would save me a lot of time over what I am doing now. Not sure why they make this so challenging.

Comment: The problem that I see is you don't get an image with that response group so you would have to make 11 total API calls to get a decent output. Is it possible to have 2 response groups in the same call?

Comment: @JorgeA.Gonzalez Yes, you can specify more than one. Please see the ItemSearch documentation here for which ones: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01/DG/ItemSearch.html

Comment: I'm not sure where you are seeing this. Using ItemLookup you can get at the data, but not ItemSearch.

Comment: @JorgeA.Gonzalez Under "Request Parameters" at the very bottom of the list. You can see this here: http://prntscr.com/40z6mb

Comment: Found it! Not sure how I missed that. Working so much better now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JorgeA.Gonzalez Great! Please accept answer if that worked for you. :)

Comment: @eComEvo, This answer should be marked "incorrect." SuperSaverShipping is different from Prime. See: http://askville.amazon.com/supersaver-shipping-differ-Amazon-Prime-discount/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=814901

Comment: @wle That is correct, they are different. However, from the API's perspective, this is an easy way to tell when a product is Prime eligible. So far I haven't seen a single case in the PAAPI where an item with `IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping` wasn't also Prime eligible. Maybe I am wrong and haven't sampled enough products, but so far it is the only reliable indicator of Prime in the API that I can find.

Comment: That's also incorrect. `IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping` encompasses a wide-range of products that are not Prime-eligible. It's almost a 50-50 chance that the two overlap.

Comment: It will say only if the lowest priced offer is IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping. Remember Lowest priced offer need not be a Prime item.

Comment: Any ideas for a more reliable way?

Answer (score 3):

The attribute `IsEligibleForPrime` tells you whether the Article is for Amazon Prime or not. It is delivered with the Response Group `OfferListings`
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_response_elements.html#IsEligibleForPrime

Comment: Is anyone getting the result true while the product is not eligible for prime?

i used php code to interpret the following:
Specifies if an item is eligible for Amazon Prime. If the flag is 1, the item is eligible. If the flag is 0 or missing, the item is not eligible.
[code]
$isPrime   =  ($xmlProduct->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->IsEligibleForPrime || 0) ? 1 : 0; 
[/code]
it seems the flag is always on.

Comment: Hi, I think it should be IsPrimeEligible instead of IsEligibleForPrime.