# Determine if Product is Eligible for 1-Day Prime via Amazon Product API?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I know you could determine if a product is eligible for FREE 2-day shipping via Prime by using attribute `"IsEligibleForPrime"` (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530977/how-do-i-tell-if-a-product-is-prime-eligible-in-the-amazon-product-advertising-a) for details) However I'm wondering if it's also possible to determine if a product is eligible for FREE 1-Day shipping via Prime?

Also while I'm asking, is it possible to determine the (guaranteed) delivery date of a product? Based on my analysis, you could have two products shipped via 2 day Prime and one of them will arrive 4 days later and the other 3 days later (this information is supplied to the customer when you add item to shopping cart on Amazon.com and proceed to checkout. My question is: is this information available via API?)

Thanks!